# Cross-browser relative href on localhost

Tags: javascript, url, cross-browser, href, location-href

I have to deal with different URL results with e.target.pathname.

In Firefox (v. 48):

```
const x = new URL("/aa/bb/", window.location) // x.pathname is "/aa/bb/"
```

In Chrome (v. 53):

```
const x = new URL("/aa/bb/", window.location) // x.pathname is "/C:/aa/bb/"
```

---

I would prefer get `x.pathname === "/aa/bb/"` (without file system notation) as Firefox gives.

---

**How to get apropriate, cross-browser, same result?** Maybe some smart, tricky solution without checking browser?

Comment: Perhaps try this on a web server instead of from file://

Comment: I think @mplungjan is correct. As running the code directly in Chrome v53 devtools outputs `"/aa/bb/"`.

Comment: One question: What is the end result you want? What is the use case. Perhaps you do not want to use URL but instead something else?

Comment: I want it works locally (dev on localhost). Server side solution is obvious, but not apropriate.

Comment: @mplungjan I have to use URL. `'<a href="...">'` must contain relative link (not absolute) and I have to parse through its parameters (for example: pathname, host, search and hash). Differences in `URL.pathname` causes different results in cross-browser work.

Comment: Do you have to use local file system too?

Comment: @mplungjan I would like to ignore file system in URL. However I want to use full localhost. Files are stored locally. One disadvantage is that Chrome adds `/C:` to local URL pathname.

Comment: localhost is not file system